# No working link to network files

Tags: 7, files, navigation

For an intranet solution I would like to add a bunch of rather static links in Drupal to network files which change from time to time and are maintained by people not using Drupal.

To achieve this I used the link functionality of CKeditor:
Protocol 
URL      file:///s:\Gloss.xls
target   popup window

When I throw `file:///s:\Gloss.xls` into any browsers address field it works perfectly (tried in IE, chrome and firefox) but from a Drupal node clicking on the link explained above, the browsers inspection reveals `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///s:\Gloss.xls` in chrome and firefox, only in IE it works.

What do I need to do to get it working in chrome or, at least in firefox?

Comment: What do you mean by "from within Drupal"?

Comment: I try to clearify it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble comes from your browser. See the answer from this question :
[How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)

> Some browsers, like modern versions of Chrome, will even refuse to
>   cross from the http protocol to the file protocol, so you'd better
>   make sure you open this locally using the file protocol if you want to
>   do this stuff at all.

Maybe another approach is to make a script witch will get the file from the server side and send it to the client in streaming.